# Combine 2 json api's response in one

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 json files and both have save data structure same keys names and everything and I want to combine the response of both apis in one and load it further in one table. here is my code.

```
`const response = await axios.get(URL, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  const response2 = await axios.get(URL2, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });`
```

these are 2 responses now I want to combine them both in one. please help.

i want to combine both responses in one.

Comment: You can create an array of responses, or a new object

Comment: If both of those responses are arrays - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

```
    const response1 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Test1',
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'test2',
     
    },
  ];

  const response2 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Test3',
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'test4',
     
    },
  ];



// merge the two arrays
  const mergedArray = [...reponse1, ...reponse2];
```

Comment: tried but didnt work